# How do you return to the start of a Mysql::Result result set

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

If you use something like `each_hash` to loop over a `Mysql::Result` set in Ruby when using the Mysql gem then you end up at the end of the result set and any subsequent `each_hash` loop doesn't have anything to loop over.

I see there is a `Mysql::Result#row_seek` method, which expects a `Mysql::RowOffset` object. But I'm unable to find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 3):

Actually found that `Mysql::Result#data_seek` takes an integer that seems to do the trick, e.g.:

```
result.data_seek(0)
```